# Javascript changing object value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a really quick question. In my html script tag i have a Box() function that serves as a class for 5 boxes.

I am creating the boxes like this

```
    var boxes = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        var d = 50;
        var y = Math.random() * 250;

        boxes[i] = new Box(d, y, d, 255);
    }


    function Box(x, y, dimension, color) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dimension = dimension;
        this.color = color;
    }

    Box.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,100,0,1)";

        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.dimension, this.dimension);

        this.x += 5;
    }
```

And drawing the boxes like this

```
    function draw() {

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.save();

        //CLEAR THE CANVAS
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 550, 400);

        for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {

            var box = boxes[i];

            box.draw(ctx);

            if (box.x > 500) {

                var index = array.boxes(box);
                boxes.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }

        ctx.restore();
    }

    //DRAW ALL BOXES EVERY 30 FRAME
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw();', 30);
```

The boxes is drawn just fine, but the x of the Object does not increase, can someone tell me why?

Comment: How are you actually creating these boxes? Need a more complete code example.

Comment: you mean you want it to be `static` ?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with html code as well? it is faster to test

Comment: how do I attach a js file then? Or do you want the entire html file?

Comment: @MortenHøgseth, How do you know that `x` doesn't increase? I do not see any reason why it wouldn't increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think that `x` doesn't increase? It does actually, your issue is that you are using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/navDq/1/)

```
//DRAW ALL BOXES EVERY 30 FRAME
var loopTimer = setInterval(draw, 300);
```